# Split backup on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-backups

I am doing a split backup such as:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [A] 
TO DISK = N'L:\sql_bak\A_full.bak',  
   DISK = N'M:\sql_bak\A_full2.bak',
   DISK = N'O:\sql_bak\A_full3.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  
     NAME = N'A-Full Database Backup', 
     SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  
     STATS = 10
GO
```

I get an error:

> Message Executed as user: DOMAIN\sqlserviceaccount. The volume on the
>   device "L:\sql_bak\A_full.bak" is not part of the media set that is
>   currently being processed. Ensure that the backup devices are loaded
>   with the correct media.
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3258) BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>   [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013) The step failed.

In one of the blog posts I read that I can use FORMAT to resolve this issue but formatting any volume of a media set renders the entire media set unusable.

Please suggest.

Answer (score -2):

I went to Run->diskmgmt.msc and formated the three disks manually. Created the folder sql_dat in all the three drives and then I started the backup and it ran successfully.

Comment: You are confusing the formatting of a **disk** with the formatting of a SQL Server **backup**. The two are unrelated and your problem will reappear.

Comment: @usr Ohkay. then what do you suggest please?

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to diagnose the problem. Probably, the existing file contained some left over backup. SQL Server backup files can contain multiple backups.

Comment: @usr I removed all other backups and executed the job but it was failing with the same error until I manually formatted the disks as I mentioned earlier. But as you said it is not a permanent fix and we have to find some other solution.